# Wordpress not updating css line-height

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm editing the custom css on wordpress.com and I'm trying to override the line-height that is in `ie.css` which I don't believe I have any power over (I think wordpress injects)

here is the css code I wrote to override a style in `ie.css`

```
.ie7 .main-navigation li a {
    line-height: auto !important;
}
```

For some odd reason the css won't update, even if I make it look like this:

```
a {
    line-height: auto !important;
}
```

I've inspected the elements to see if the style is being applied, it's not. I've cleared my cache multiple times also.. still nothing.

Does wordpress.com custom css not allow line-height editing? What could be some possibilities on why a style wouldn't render on wordpress.com?

The link to the blog is: http://letstalktermites.wordpress.com/

**EDIT**: I'm only having these troubles in ie7 and ie8

Comment: If the rule doesn't show up in the inspector, the style sheet isn't being loaded. Have you triple checked it is, and the rule is in there?

Comment: Yep, quadrupedal checked hehe. What's funny is if I apply the exact same rule without the 'a' so it would be styling the li, it works fine (but that is only when I style it without line-height (e.g. margin: 0)

Comment: @Jrod Updated my question to reflect a link to the blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no 'auto' value for line-height. try 'normal'...

Comment: Ah! Okay, I've changed it, but no luck. :(

Comment: Have you tried to use Firebug to see, if your CSS is overridden sometimes? Give me some more info...

Comment: Try to reconstruct your error with jsfiddle.net then I can fix your code better

Comment: @algorhythm if it helps any, I've linked the blog url in my question above.

Comment: @DennisMartinez The 'line-height' property is already set to the links in your navigation. Maybe you have to clear your cache? I didn't find, where you set the CSS-Property, maybe somewhere in your javascript? Or in HTML?

Comment: The line-height is being set on my navigation links from ie.css (if you see other places, please let me know) , I should have mentioned to view this in ie8 and ie7. I'll updated my question. I have no control over ie.css.

Comment: Wait wait wait... fixed! Thanks! I'm kicking myself in the head right now.. But thanks! I just had the wrong class on the selector on my end.. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DennisMartinez maybe the IE is not able to interpret the '!important'-keyword. Try without. I think you don't need it.

Comment: @DennisMartinez no prob, have fun ;)